# htaccess url rewrite but the ID changes

Tags: .htaccess

I wondering if it is possible to rewrite a url that might look something like this

```
www.example.com/item.php?id=1 to a www.example/item.php without the `?id=1`
```

Please note that 1 is for the product id so it might change to 2 or any number depending on what product the user choose

**My current htaccess**

My current `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ test/main/pages/account/$1 [L]   // **the item.php file is in the item folder**
ErrorDocument 404 /test/main/pages/general/index.php
Options -Indexes
AuthName "main"
```

**I did it like**

```
<?php
include('global.php'); ///database connection

function create_guid()
    {
            $microTime = microtime();
        list($a_dec, $a_sec) = explode(" ", $microTime);

        $dec_hex = dechex($a_dec* 1000000);
        $sec_hex = dechex($a_sec);

         ensure_length($dec_hex, 5);
         ensure_length($sec_hex, 6);

        $guid = "";
        $guid .= $dec_hex;
        $guid .= create_guid_section(3);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= $sec_hex;
        $guid .= create_guid_section(6);

        return $guid;

    }

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Product (`pid`, `Guid`, `price`) VALUES
(13, '".$guid."', 13)");
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

also i did it using PDO because am I not a big fan of mysql

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to understand what you want. You want to rewrite "www.example.com/item.php?id=1" to "www.example.com/item/1" ?

Comment: @Lucas Willems sorry if i havent example it well... I have edited the question. What I mean is if I have a url for like `wwww.example.com/test.php?id=1` if it is possibe to rewrite it without having to show the `?id=1`

Comment: Ok. Now, I understand. I will answer to your question.

Comment: @LucasWillems please note that `?id=1` will not always be `1` it might change to 2 depending on what item is showing in `item.php` page. So what I am saying is that 1 might change to 2 or 12 or 20,

Comment: Without an ID, how to target the specific product, you can do like 1_item.php or something or create a controller file to set the session with the ID and redirect to item.php page. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @Amy I'm trying to guess what you actually want to ask. Is that you want to make your URL pretty so that user can type in something like www.example.com/item/1 in his browser, while a PHP script handle all similar request and be able to get the 1 as parameter?

Comment: @LarryMok I am doing the opposite :p. I am trying to stop users from type 1 or 2 or 3 in the url. If I knew how to md5 the `1` it will be better but I am still a newbie to this and I can't find a good guide on how to md5 for an id but they r alot on storing it in a database.

this is how my ur looks on a allitem.php. 
`<a href="item.php?id=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>">View</a>`

as u can see I `echo` the `pid` which mean in the url it will look like the one on my question which means someone could change the `pid` to 2 or 3 or anynumber and I don't want that.

Comment: So without an ID being passed, how does `item.php` know what item to render? Or is the id just completely ignored?

Comment: @Jon Lin read the page renders based on `<a href="item.php?id=<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>">View</a>` and on item.php i have a get `if (isset($_GET['pid'])) ` to get the pid.

Comment: md5 is easy, you just md5('a string'); but it's a hashing algorithm (that means one way, e.g. you can convert a to b, but not b to a). If you want a more "secure" URL so that people cannot guess the URL, you should not use integer sequence at all. Instead you can assign a random string to each "record".

Comment: But there is no `?pid=(some number)`, so `$_GET['pid'])` is never set. And if you want to get rid of the `id=(some number)` part of the query string as well, then `$_GET['id'])` isn't going to be set either. Thus you won't know what the item ID is.

Comment: @LarryMok can u post an example of how u think will be the best way to assign random string to the url please

Comment: @JonLin without the echo `$row['pid']` the page wouldn't render. thats it will just be like `?id=` on the url. right now the way i have done renders the page but anyone couldnt change whatever output of the url to 2 or 3 and it will render that page based on the `pid` they have type in. Thats if only that `pid` exist in my database

Comment: @Amy - the answer from saran banerjee below is a good starting point :)

Answer (score 3):

Since your main motive here to keep people form guessing the id in url and since as pointed out by **lucas william** that the way you want it is not possible in .htaccess instead you can store the id of each product in the database as guid format(this format of id storage into database is used by **sugarCRM**) which is also a proper substitute to satisfy you required and you can use that id to uniquely identify you product table each records:

The functions to create guid is as follows:

```
function create_guid()
    {
            $microTime = microtime();
        list($a_dec, $a_sec) = explode(" ", $microTime);

        $dec_hex = dechex($a_dec* 1000000);
        $sec_hex = dechex($a_sec);

         ensure_length($dec_hex, 5);
         ensure_length($sec_hex, 6);

        $guid = "";
        $guid .= $dec_hex;
        $guid .= create_guid_section(3);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= create_guid_section(4);
        $guid .= '-';
        $guid .= $sec_hex;
        $guid .= create_guid_section(6);

        return $guid;

    }
    function create_guid_section($characters)
    {
        $return = "";
        for($i=0; $i<$characters; $i++)
        {
            $return .= dechex(mt_rand(0,15));
        }
        return $return;
    }

    function ensure_length(&$string, $length)
    {
        $strlen = strlen($string);
        if($strlen < $length)
        {
            $string = str_pad($string,$length,"0");
        }
        else if($strlen > $length)
        {
            $string = substr($string, 0, $length);
        }
    }
```

Now using the above function you can generate the id as:

```
$guid = create_guid(); //guid is of the format 79cb3604-e634-a142-d9cb-5113745b31e2 which you can see is quite impossible to guess.
```

Also I would sugest that you keep the auto increment field in your product table.
Because it always a good idea to maintain a auto incremented field in a table to uniquely identity the records.

I hope this can be of some help

Edit :

what you need to do is add a field in you database product table named "guid"
so say your current database product table structure has the following fields:

```
id, name, price  //where id is the auto incremented
```

after adding the field guid it becomes

```
id, guid, name, price //where id is auto incremented field and guid uniquely identifies each row in the product table
```

and when you do the insert of the product data in the database product table you generate the guid using the above code and insert it. ie

for example

```
$sql = "Insert into product_table('guid','product_name',product_price) values('".$guid."','product1','59.00');
```

so an example data in your product table will look like this:

```
1, 79cb3604-e634-a142-d9cb-5113745b31e2, product1, 59.00
```

Now in the product.php page with url say

```
yoursite.com/product.php?guid=79cb3604-e634-a142-d9cb-5113745b31e2
```

instead of using the url

```
yoursite.com/product.php?id=1
```

you can easily query the data from the database product table in relation to "guid" which of course also uniquely identifies each row in your product table in the database there by elimiting the risk of user guessing your id in url of the webpage.

I hope this gives you an idea of what i am trying to explain.

Comment: so this code will change the item `PID` in the url to a random unique numbers and letters? if so will i need to add this code in my `item.php page`?

Comment: I have edited the answer so that you can get an idea of what i am trying to explain

Comment: I love  you so much for explaining this to me... I will try it and let you know how far i get

Comment: whats the length of `guid` for the database

Comment: one more think what page or file name will the code go into please i try adding it to product.php and its having problems with the code `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in`

Comment: make the datatype of the guid to char(36). and the 3 function(create_guid(),create_guid_section(),ensure_length())  will go to the page where you are inserting the product info(along with the guid) into database.Also I made change in the function create_guid() so that the  syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC get solved. I think this should do the trick.

Comment: 2 questions 1) public function wouldn't work because it not in a class and 2) I have about 300 data what will be the easy where to assign the random guid to it?

Comment: well I remove the public keyword as you can see in the function create_guid() and as for update the data u need to make a php script to update all the existing rows of product table with guid and then run it.

Comment: I have editing my question to show how i did it but it doesn't work still

Comment: in the edited code section in your question you need to add functions (create_guid_section(),ensure_length()) and along with that you need to add this line: $guid = create_guid(); before the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess, rewrite "www.example.com/item.php?id=1" to "www.example/item.php" is not possible because, how can we know, with an url like "www.example/item.php", if the product id is 1 or 2 ? It's impossible. So, with .htaccess, it's not possible.

However, you can cheat and use, simply, PHP and session variables, to do this rewriting, even if it's not a good solution. So, let your links under their current shape, with the get id parameter, and just add in your item.php file, a condition that will save the id value in a session variable and redirect to item.php if the id parameter is not empty.